# Taylor series for square root of exp[i x]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, mathematical-physics

I need to find 
$$
\textrm{Lim}_{x\rightarrow 0} \sqrt{-\exp[i x]}
$$
mathematica says it is $- i$ but how it is so. I would say it is $i$ because if I take limit then $\exp[i x]$ becomes 1 and $\sqrt{-1}$ is iota. Can anyone help in understanding this.

Comment: $\sqrt{-1} = \pm i$

Comment: What's the meaning of these square brackets ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm guessing, nothing whatsoever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-integer powers of complex numbers are defined as $z^\alpha \equiv e^{\alpha\,\text{Log}(z)}$ where $\text{Log}$ is *some* complex logarithm. The [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) is multivalued (since $e^{z} = e^{z + 2\pi i n}$ for any integer $n$) so there are infinitely many choices. The common choice is to use the so-called [principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch#Complex_logarithms) of the logarithm for which $z^\alpha \equiv e^{\alpha(\log|z| + i\arg(z))}$ where $\arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi]$ is the [complex argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)). Any definition of a complex logarithm requires a [branch-cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) which is a curve from $0$ to $\infty$ for which the logarithm has a discontinuity.

For this particular problem we have 
$$\sqrt{-e^{ix}} = \sqrt{e^{ix + \pi i}} = e^{\frac{i}{2}\arg(e^{ix + \pi i})}$$ 
and in [Mathematica the branch cut is along the negative real axis](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatDoNotHaveUniqueValues.html) so for small positive $x$ we have $\arg(e^{ix + \pi i})\approx -\pi$ and for small negative $x$ we have $\arg(e^{ix + \pi i}) \approx  \pi$. This means that
$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\sqrt{-e^{ix}} = -i~~~~\text{and}~~~~\lim_{x\to 0-}\sqrt{-e^{ix}} = +i$$ 
so the limit does not exist. The problem here is that the discontinuity of the logarithm is along where you want to take the limit.

Comment: How you say $arg(i x+i \pi)\approx -\pi$ for small positive $x$ and $\pi$ for small negative $x$. Generally argument of a complex number $z$ is $\tan^{-1}(\frac{Im[z]}{Re[z]})$. How would I get $\pm \pi$ with this logic.

Comment: @Parveen There was some typos: it should be $\arg e^{ix+i\pi}$. As for computing it see the link I added above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part

Comment: Now everything is fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As usual, Mathematica is right and accurate.

It says $i$ for the left limit and $-i$ for the right limit. The limit itself does not exist. This is because in the complex you have to choose between branches.

Answer (score -1):

When I solved this limit using MATLAB, the result was `i`, and analytically you do get `i`, so I guess Mathematica is probably giving you wrong results.